# Disable Required validation for a specific button & textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to disable required validator field for a specific button click which is not check only a textbox. i've tried this code in the button click but not worked. so need this type of code how solve.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (TextBox1 == null)
    {
        RequiredFieldValidator1.EnableViewState = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `EnableViewState` has nothing to do with validation and `TextBox1 == null` will never be true if it exists

Comment: how can i done this? need an idea

Comment: Use [`ValidatorGroups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx), this button gets a different group than the RequiredFieldValidator, voila.

Comment: do you have any link validatorGroup code? plz share@TimSchmelter

Comment: Have you clicked at the link i've provided in my last comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `CausesValidation="false"` on your button property.

If you wish to validate that particular button with some other TextBox or control you can set `ValidationGroup="groupA"` to those controls and name it same group.

Comment: which code will set in the groupA. is it need to js@mer hardik

Comment: no you can set on each controls that needs validation and leave out of group for those controls where you don't want to apply validation. 
or you can just CausesValidation="false" on your button and it will not trigger validation

Comment: done by added a label . and with a if condition. my requirement was disable validator for only a button. thnx @mer hardik

Comment: great to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

`RequiredFieldValidator61.Visible = false;` is what worked for me. It disables the error massage.